# Help signing a P2WSH Multisig

Tags: lightning-network, multi-signature, p2wsh, bip143

I'm trying to construct a transaction in regtest mode that spends from a P2WSH 2-of-2 multisig.

Here is the funding transaction for 5 btc. It also contains a change output for 5 btc.

`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`

This is the transaction I am trying to spend from the escrow:

`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`

bitcoin-cli is giving me this error message when I try to broadcast it:

`error code: -26
error message:
non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation) (code 64)`

Here are the private keys associated with the escrow tx:

`privkey1 = "CF933A6C602069F1CBC85990DF087714D7E86DF0D0E48398B7D8953E1F03534B"
privkey2 = "BF933A6C602069F1CBC85990DF087714D7E86DF0D0E48398B7D8953E1F03534B"`

and here is the bip_143 transaction digest preimage that does into double SHA256, which is then getting signed by the private keys:

hashPrevOuts `ec4982463833211511676584168e5c2749598a966f84594d529ca4627af6f541`

hashSequence `3bb13029ce7b1f559ef5e747fcac439f1455a2ec7c5f09b72290795e70665044`

outpoint txid `35fff0ef75190ac3ead75b46713fb63da6bf642b4e064856d5778a3e21615f30`

outpoint index
`00000000`

scriptCode
`522103c2f21de0f430251d8e3987fbe89ff51f3d6f3a48b234b84b60ddb9f24d587cf52103e0948a03f50377290847d27c93d383b8ab7e2d0bc065e96e0e1136b315388b5452ae`

input_amount
`0065cd1d00000000`

sequence
`ffffffff`

hashOutputs
`0c4a4515b0c862221d8376400bef5e085aba67281d774776f1bc083294180d6b`

locktime
`00000000`

sighash
`01000000`

Full bip143 tx digest preimage:
`02000000ec4982463833211511676584168e5c2749598a966f84594d529ca4627af6f5413bb13029ce7b1f559ef5e747fcac439f1455a2ec7c5f09b72290795e7066504435fff0ef75190ac3ead75b46713fb63da6bf642b4e064856d5778a3e21615f3000000000522103c2f21de0f430251d8e3987fbe89ff51f3d6f3a48b234b84b60ddb9f24d587cf52103e0948a03f50377290847d27c93d383b8ab7e2d0bc065e96e0e1136b315388b5452ae0065cd1d00000000ffffffff0c4a4515b0c862221d8376400bef5e085aba67281d774776f1bc083294180d6b0000000001000000`

Any help with what could be going on or what to try would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, in the bip143 tx digest preimage, the scriptCode needs to be preceded by the length of the scriptCode. In this case 0x47